# First identical value distance

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I want to find the first of the following occurrences of each value. Two "for in" solves. Is there a faster method?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list("AB"))
df["A"] = [4,2,4,4,2,5,2,6,1,6,4,5,9,3,7,3,3]

for i, a1 in enumerate(df["A"][:-1]):
    for j, a2 in enumerate(df["A"][i+1:]):
        print(i,a1,j+1,a2)
        if a1 == a2:
            df["B"][i] = j+1
            break
```

So:

| source | result |
| --- | --- |
| A[0] = A[2] = 4 | B[0] = 2-0 = 2 |
| A[1] = A[4] = 2 | B[1] = 4-1 = 3 |

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 2 | NaN |
| 7 | 6 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 | NaN |
| 9 | 6 | NaN |
| 10 | 4 | NaN |
| 11 | 5 | NaN |
| 12 | 9 | NaN |
| 13 | 3 | 2 |
| 14 | 7 | NaN |
| 15 | 3 | 1 |
| 16 | 3 | NaN |

Comment: Can you include your working code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = (
    df.reset_index()
    .groupby('A')
    .apply(lambda x: x['index'].diff().shift(-1))
    .reset_index(0)
    .sort_index()
    .convert_dtypes()
    .rename(columns = {'index': 'B'})
    )
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   A     B
0   4     2
1   2     3
2   4     1
3   4     7
4   2     2
5   5     6
6   2  <NA>
7   6     2
8   1  <NA>
9   6  <NA>
10  4  <NA>
11  5  <NA>
12  9  <NA>
13  3     2
14  7  <NA>
15  3     1
16  3  <NA>
```